# Cannot find module Youch in AdonisJS Heroku

Tags: heroku, adonis.js

After doing the deploy of my AdonisJS application on Heroku. An error is encountered while trying to access the application via browser.

I'm using AdonisJS version 4.1.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'Youch'
Error: Cannot find module 'Youch'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:655:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at requireStack (/app/node_modules/require-stack/src/index.js:44:12)
    at Ioc._require (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/src/Ioc/index.js:345:12)
    at Ioc.use (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/src/Ioc/index.js:742:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app/Exceptions/Handler.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at requireStack (/app/node_modules/require-stack/src/index.js:44:12)
    at Ioc._resolveAutoloadedPath (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/src/Ioc/index.js:265:20)
    at Ioc.use (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/src/Ioc/index.js:739:19)
    at Server._handleException (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/framework/src/Server/index.js:245:36)
    at _executeServerMiddleware.then.then.catch (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/framework/src/Server/index.js:441:14)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
```

I want to make that mistake, but I do not know how.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try `const Youch = use(‘youch’)` instead `const Youch = use(‘Youch’)`.

Comment: What is the difference?